# Ito's Lemma: from $df$ to $df^2$ to get $\operatorname{Var}[df]$

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, variance, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the stochastic process
\begin{align*}
dX_t&=\mu_t dt+\sqrt{Y_t}X_t dB_t \\
dY_t&=m_t dt+s\sqrt{Y_t} dW_t
\end{align*}
where $dB_tdW_t=\rho dt$, $s$ is a constant and $\mu_t$ and $m_t$ are well-behaved drifts.

According to Ito's formula:
\begin{align*}
df(X_t,Y_t) &= \left(\frac{1}{2}Y_tX_t^2f_{xx}(X_t,Y_t)+\rho s Y_tX_t f_{xy}(X_t,Y_t)+\frac{1}{2}s^2Y_tf_{yy}(X_t,Y_t)+\mu_t f_x(X_t,Y_t)+m_t f_y(X_t,Y_t)\right)dt \\
&\;\;\;\;\; +\sqrt{Y_t} X_t f_{x}(X_t,Y_t)dB_t+s\sqrt{Y_t} f_{y}(X_t,Y_t)dW_t.
\end{align*}
My question: **Is the following assertion correct?**
\begin{align*}
df(X_t,Y_t)^2 &= \bigg( Y_t X_t^2f_{x}(X_t,Y_t)^2+2\rho s X_tY_t f_{x} (X_t,Y_t)f_y(X_t,Y_t)+s^2 Y_t f_y(X_t,Y_t)^2\bigg)\text{d}t
\end{align*}
This expression then gives $\operatorname{Var}[df]=E[df^2]-E[df]^2=E[df^2]=df^2$, because $E[df]$ is of order $dt$ and squaring it makes it negligible whereas $df^2$ is non-random.

Comment: There is a factor 2 in the middle term of the binomial formula for the square.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Great spot. Thank you. I corrected it! :) Can you see any other problems with it?

Comment: No, it looks good, the quadratic variation of $dU=adt+bdB+cdW$ is the square of the stochastic part, $(bdB+cdW)^2$, with the averaging $(dB)^2\sim dt$ as per the law of large numbers.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thanks very much. If you leave a short answer, I'll accept and upvote it immediately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to mark this question as answered:

@[Lutz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/115115/lutz-lehmann) agrees that the equation in the question is correct
\begin{align*}
df(X_t,Y_t)^2 &= \bigg( Y_t X_t^2f_{x}(X_t,Y_t)^2+2\rho s X_tY_t f_{x} (X_t,Y_t)f_y(X_t,Y_t)+s^2 Y_t f_y(X_t,Y_t)^2\bigg)dt.
\end{align*}